# Performance Enhancement while inserting HBase table through hive external table

Tags: pyspark, hive, hbase

I have to insert a dataframe to an Hbase table on PySpark. I create a hive external table based on the HBase table. In the PySpark code, I create a temp view from the dataframe. After that, I select data from tempView and insert it into the hive external table, and data is inserted into the HBase table. Everything works fine, there is no problem in the process.

My problem is that the insert process is slower than we expected. I also tried the write method by defining the catalog but the performance was much worse.

It takes 27 minutes to insert 470 MB of data (2000 columns, 200 000 rows)

I am running .py file via spark-submit.

Do you have any recommendations to insert data faster?

Comment: disable WAL( Write Ahead Log), see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hbaseintegration

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I checked the document and I added "set spark.hive.hbase.wal.enabled=false"  to spark-submit. I also added via spark sql but there is no improvement about performance. I am not sure if I managed to do it.